# AngularJS. Displaying custom popup on user's attempt to leave the page

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Is it possible to **synchronously** display bootstrap modal (instead of native confirm) when user tries:

1. change route
2. leave the page

(AngularJS)

Comment: Why do you want synchronous?

Comment: to stop javascript execution. If not block - changing route/leaving the page happening before user press anything on popup. Native confirm - blocking, bootstrap modal - not blocking

Comment: you don't need stop javascript execution, you must change your mindset

Comment: @AbelRodríguez what do you mean. Could you advice me a solution ? How to display bootstrap modal and let user makes his choice before transition happen ?

Answer (score 0):

You must separate your code into two different functions.

If you have this:

```
var txt;
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
    // Put this in a function ...
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    // ... and this in another function
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

Would like this:

```
var onOkClick = function(){    
  txt = "You pressed OK!";
};

var onCancelClick = function(){    
  txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
};
```

And in the buttons of your modal:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick="onOkClick()">OK</button>
<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' onclick="onCancelClick()">Cancel</button>
```